# Magento 1.8 - How to remove pagination?

Tags: magento

How I can remove pagination from Magento 1.8? I need display all products in one page.
I need this:

> E.g. I open a
>   category, at the top of page will show big picture and below the
>   smaller and can be moved without a person switches to the second, third
>   side?

google translate. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to infinite scroll. There are so many free extension available.

http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/blog/2013/07/magento-product-list-ajax-scroll-v2-0/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/strategery-infinitescroll-2-9213.html

And don't worry about Magento 1.8 version. These extension will work perfectly.

Hope will help!

Answer (score 1):

comment on this gettoolbarhtml() check following file

**`/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`**

comment below line

```
  //echo $this->getToolbarHtml()
```

Comment: hello you will search ajax product list scroll on http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect